# Calculating the difference between max and min in different table

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

[Table major](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtGCK.jpg)

[Table student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR9ru.jpg)

How do I calculate the age difference between the oldest and the youngest Computer Sciences major?

In this the case, should I use INNER JOIN or OUTER JOIN?

Comment: Please add what you have done so far.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that a student will only have one major in this dataset?

Comment: So far I could only figure out how to print out the max and min of age in the student table. select min(age) as min_age,max(age) as max_age from student; and yes this is just a dummy dataset that I've created just for practice. I need to familiarize myself with the JOIN case. I'd be grateful for any hint given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be computed easily using a combination of the `min()` and `max()` aggregate functions.

> ... should I use INNER JOIN or OUTER JOIN

It doesn't make sense to keep any records that don't have a matching row in the other table. That means that an inner join would make the most sense here.

---

```
select
    m.mname
    , max(s.age) - min(s.age) as age_difference
from
    student s
    join major m
        on s.sid = m.sid
where
    m.mname = 'Computer Sciences'
group by
    m.mname
```

Comment: Oh I see. So in order to pick the 'age' I need to isolate everything else. Thank you for your time.